# Delaying in VB.net

Tags: vba, vb.net, delay

I need to wait 3-4 seconds after a button has been pressed before i can check for it, here is my code under `button1_click`:

```
While Not File.Exists(LastCap)
    Application.DoEvents()
    MsgBox("testtestetstets")
End While

PictureBox1.Load(LastCap)
```

Comment: Why do you have to wait?

Comment: Why you dont use a `Timer`? with `Interval = 3000`ms. On tick stop Timer and do what you need

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delay code execution in Visual Basic (VB6)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95112/how-do-i-delay-code-execution-in-visual-basic-vb6)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the reason you are needing to wait is for the file to be created try using a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) and respond to the [`Created`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created.aspx) and [`Changed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed.aspx) Events that way you are responding to an event rather than arbitrarily waiting a select period of time.

Something like:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    FileSystemWatcher1.Path = 'Your Path Here
    FileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = True
   'Do what you need to todo to initiate the file creation
End Sub

Private Sub FileSystemWatcher1_Created(sender As Object, e As System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs) Handles FileSystemWatcher1.Created, FileSystemWatcher1.Changed
    If e.Name = LastCap Then
        If (System.IO.File.Exists(e.FullPath)) Then
            FileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = False
            PictureBox1.Load(e.FullPath)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use, although not recommended:

```
Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000) 'ms
```

This will wait 3 seconds, but also block everything else on the same thread. If you run this in the form your user-interface will not response until the wait is over.

just as a side note: use `MessageBox.Show("My message")` instead of `MsgBox` (latter is from old VB).

Answer (score 5):

If you want your form to continue to function while the 3 seconds pass, you can add a Timer control instead, with some code like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' set the timer
    Timer1.Interval = 3000 'ms
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Stop()
    'add delayed code here
    '...
    '...
    MessageBox.Show("Delayed message...")
End Sub
```

Drag and drop a Timer control from your toolbox to your form. It's not visible at runtime

Answer (score 5):

or better yet making a wait function using stop watch, this wont halt the process in the same thread like thread sleep

```
 ' Loops for a specificied period of time (milliseconds)
Private Sub wait(ByVal interval As Integer)
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    sw.Start()
    Do While sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < interval
        ' Allows UI to remain responsive
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
    sw.Stop()
End Sub
```

usage

```
wait(3000)
```

for 3 sec delay

Answer (score 3):

You could use this

```
Public Sub BeLazy()
    For i = 1 To 30
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        Application.DoEvents()
    Next
End Sub
```

It will delay for 3 seconds.